# Search engines/algorithms to find closest continuous (floating point) sampled signal?

Tags: algorithm, search, data-structures, floating-point

Given any two sequences/vectors of M real numbers, I can easily compute their closeness or correlation using a variety of metrics/norms. But is there an efficient structure to look up the closest M-sequence in a corpus of sequences, or the closest subsequence of a longer sequence? A sliding window would be the naive/brute-force approach. Does anyone know of anything better, though?

EDIT: As I'm typing this, I'm thinking that something like searching in a K-d tree might work, where each offset is a separate dimension in an M-dimensional space?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a sliding window would work, you're probably doing a [cross-correlation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-correlation), in which case you can use [FFTs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_Fourier_transform) to solve your problem faster by a factor of O(n/log(n)).

So if you have a vector V, and a corpus of C other vectors, and all vectors are size N, then the sliding window solution would take O(N^2 * C) time.  By using FFTs you can reduce a single sliding window from O(N^2) to O(N log N), so the total time would be O(CN log N).

If you aren't familiar with FFTs then you will probably need to read up on them before using them, but the general idea is this:

```
# If you forget to take the complex conjugate of V you'll be doing a
# convolution instead of a correlation
V' := Fft(Conjugate(V))

for each vector W in C:
    W' := Fft(W)
    P := W' * V'   # Multiplication here is the dot product
    R := inverse_Fft(P)
    # Check through the vector R for any spikes, a large value at
    # R[i] indicates that if you shift W' by i then it will
    # correlate strongly with W
```

Caveats:

1) If you're doing correlations at all you'll need to normalize your vectors, or at least do something to make sure you don't get false positives from vectors whose values are just larger and more positive than other vectors.  If yours is a typical use case of looking for a signal in noise, though, then you're fine.

2) FFTs correlate under the assumption that all of these signals are circular.  If you don't want to treat them like they're circular then you need to add a buffer of 0's to the end of each vector to double its length.

Comment: This is really cool! I'm actually studying electrical engineering as a major, but I had no idea that the frequency domain would be useful for this problem! Sadly, I'm trying to implement this in ActionScript (o_o) so it's easier said than done, but I'm looking forward to trying this out!

Answer (score 4):

The problem with acceleration structures (such as K-d trees) is that they become less effective as the dimensionality (M, in the question) increases.  If your M is very large, you might be better off with a linear search.

If your M is of moderate size (up to something like 6 or so, as a ballpark guess?), it may be worth trying a K-d tree.  There are search structures available for higher-dimensional spaces; I recommend looking up *Foundations of Multidimensional and Metric Data Structures*, by Samet.